# Submit form on checkout process step by step jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm working in a shopping page, right now with the checkout section. I want to show a progress, first asking for facturation address, then shipping address, payment etc. Like this:

[image: http://picpaste.com/pics/Captura_de_pantalla_de_2014-07-30_10_34_38-kB0KIzfQ.1406709555.png]

I have the follow code corresponding to the steps on checkout progress.

```
<div class="progressContent" >

    <form id="form1" class="update_form" action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Dirección de facturación</h2>
                <p>
                    Introduzca la dirección a la que quiere asociar la facturación de la compra, no el envío.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $name[0] ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $name[1]." ".$name[2] ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $calle ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $localidad ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="localidad">Localidad:</label>
                <input type="text" name="localidad" value="" required />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

    <form id="form2" class="update_form" action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Dirección de envio</h2>
                <p>
                    Introduzca la dirección en la que desea recibir el pedido.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $name[0] ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $name[1]." ".$name[2] ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $calle ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $localidad ?>" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="localidad">Localidad:</label>
                <input type="text" name="localidad" value="" required />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

    <form id="form3" class="update_form" action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Método de envío</h2>
                <p>
                    Seleccione el método de envío que desea. Los gastos de envío corren a cargo del cliente.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="envio normal" title="Envío normal">
            Envío normal
        </div>
        <p class="textoEnvio">
            Se relizará la entrega por parte de la empresa tal, el tiempo estimado son unos 3 días laborables.
        </p>
        <div class="envio express" title="Envío rápido">
            Envío express
        </div>
        <p class="textoEnvio">
            Se relizará la entrega por parte de la empresa tal, el tiempo estimado son unos 2 días laborables.
        </p>
        <p class="nota">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>Recuerda que los gastos de envío no están incluidos en el precio, y se habrían de pagar en el momento de la entrega.
        </p>
    </form>

    <form id="form4" class="update_form" action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Método de pago</h2>
                <p>
                    Seleccione el método de pago preferido para realizar la compra actual.
                </p>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input id="tarjeta" class="pago" type="radio" name="tipoPago" value="tarjeta">
                <label class="selectorPagos tarjeta" for="tarjeta"></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="paypal" class="pago" type="radio" name="tipoPago" value="paypal">
                <label class="selectorPagos paypal" for="paypal"></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="ingreso" class="pago" type="radio" name="tipoPago" value="cuenta">
                <label class="selectorPagos ingreso" for="ingreso"></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="progressBottons" >
    <a href="#" class="botonComprar compra" id="continuar" title="Siguiente" type="button" >Continuar</a>
    <a href="#" class="botonComprar " id="anterior" title="Atrás" type="button" >Anterior</a>
</div>
```

I want to submit every time I click on "continuar" to store information with jquery/ajax in mysql database, and the same with the next step. I've try with this:

```
$('.progressContent').on('click','#continuar', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.progressContent').children('.update_form').eq(i-2).submit( function() {

        dataString = $('.progressContent').children('.update_form').eq(i-2).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./php/api.php?facturacion=1",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });


    setInterval();

});
```

but that doesn't work. How could do this the right way? I made sure the form was selected correctly.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Does the AJAX query fire? What does `dataString` look like if you output it?

Comment: Have you tried using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to determine what's wrong?

Comment: AJAX query fire, dataString content nombre=&apellidos=&direccion=&ciudad=&localidad= , so work ok, but ajax url, I have php file, returning a string, ej. "ok". but when I print "data", nothing shows.

Comment: I already solve it, the problem was that, when you make an asyn submit with jquery, first you have to call `.submit()` method, and then you create the handler `.submit(function ( ) { //whatever }`.